# Is it possible to change ngbDatepicker formatter dynamically?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, dateformatter, ngb-datepicker

I am looking for a way to toggle between different date formatters (e.g.  mm-dd-yyyy / dd-mm-yyyy) on the ngbDatepicker control based on the user selection.

Any ideas/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Of course (impossible is nothing). But before is necesary you undestand DateParserFormater and DateAdapter see [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685403/how-to-change-ngbdatepicker-date-format-from-json-to-yyyy-mm-dd/56686978#56686978)

In your case, you only need work with a CustomDateParseFormat

Well, the only thing that we need is that the functions parse/format and fromModel/toModel depending form one variable. I don't found a great way also inject a service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MaskController{
  mask:string="yyyy/MM/dd"
  public setMask(mask)
  {
    this.mask=mask;
  }
}
```

And our CustomDateParserFormatter inject in constructor

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomDateParserFormatter {
  constructor(private maskController:MaskController){}
  get mask()
  {
    return this.maskController.mask;
  }
   ...
}
```

well, the only thing we need is change our function depending the value of "mask", and when call to

```
maskController.setMask(...)
```

Our ngbDatePicker work as we want. Y put an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-64knsp-leqmh1?file=app%2Fdatepicker-adapter.ts) (only two "mask" allowed dd/MM/yyyy and yyyy/MM/dd)

NOTE:In the stackblitz I change the dateFormat too. Simply not included in provider the CustomDateAdapter