# NbDatePicker don't show some names in Spanish

Tags: angular, datepicker, translation, nebular

my problem is than I use the component Nb-DatePicker in my project, I used
`{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "es-MX"}` in my app.component to show in spanish, but if February, April, May, August or December are selected are not showed, I think than it must be related to the translation but I don't know,  when I delete the line `{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "es-MX"}` it works fine, what could I do to show the names in Spanish and get over the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vmsnob?file=src%2Fpolyfills.ts)

In app.module I add

```
import '@angular/common/locales/global/es-MX';
```

And in provider your:

```
providers:[{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-MX' }]
```

I also need add in the polyfills.ts this line (But I think that is because is a stackblitz)

```
import '@angular/localize/init';  //<---see if you need add this line
```

The other way is create a CustomDateAdapter and CustomDateParserFormatter (if you want to input the date using, e.g. dd/mm/yyyy and a DatepickerEsMX that extends from NgbDatepickerI18n to "translate" the month names and weekdays names (the DateAdapter and DatePArser is explained in this [old SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685403/how-to-change-ngbdatepicker-date-format-from-json-to-yyyy-mm-dd/56686978#56686978), the use of extends NgbDatePickerI18 is explain in the [example of the docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#i18n) (*)

```
providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-MX' },
            {provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter},
            {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: CustomDateParserFormatter}
            { provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: DatepickerEsMx },
```

(*) The DatePickerEsMX can be like

```
@Injectable()
export class DatepickerEsMX extends NgbDatepickerI18n {

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private localeId: string) {
        super();
    }

  getWeekdayShortName(weekday: number): string {
        return I18N_VALUES.es.weekdays[weekday - 1];
    }
    getMonthShortName(month: number): string {
        return I18N_VALUES.es.months[month - 1];
    }
    getMonthFullName(month: number): string {
        return I18N_VALUES.es.fullMonths[month - 1];
    }

    getDayAriaLabel(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
        return `${date.day}-${date.month}-${date.year}`;
    }
}
```