# Angular Bootstrap Datepicker custom date format dd-MMM-yyyy (e.g., "01-Sep-2023")

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap-calendar

I have also use NgbDateParserFormatter but not solve this problem date format - dd-MMM-yyyy (e.g., "01-Sep-2023")

*component.html*

```
<div class="input-group">
            <input
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                name="dp"
                [(ngModel)]="model"
                ngbDatepicker
                #d="ngbDatepicker"
            />
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
        </div>
```

```
Model: {{ model | json }}
```

Result

```
Model: {
  "year": 2023,
  "month": 9,
  "day": 21
}
```

*component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbAlertModule, NgbDatepickerModule, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [NgbDatepickerModule, NgbAlertModule, FormsModule, JsonPipe],
    templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html',
})
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup {
    model: NgbDateStruct;
}
```

Refernce: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example to reproduce your issue in the question? Or in the StackBlitz? Thanks.

Comment: I have maximum tried.

Comment: it's a bit old, but I think that mush be work:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685403/how-to-change-ngbdatepicker-date-format-from-json-to-yyyy-mm-dd/56686978#56686978

Comment: I tried this also but did not find the solution.
Returns Invalid Date selectedDate- [object Object]